# How to connect to a wifi which password only has 6 letters?

Tags: wifi, password

1st, the WiFi is a mobile hotspot, I can not change its password unless I am able to connect to it first. The only way to connect to the device is by using WiFi.

I have reset the device and I have the default password, but the wifi's default password only has 6 letters. I think due to security reasons, the minimum wifi password on all modern system requires at least 8 letters.

I have tried using my Android phone, Linux system and Win10 system, all of them won't even allow me to try to connect to the device...WTF

Any idea how to override this?

Comment: what is the device in question? ... make/model

Comment: ZMI a mobile power bank + Wi-Fi

Comment: afaik the minimum 8 is for WPA. Maybe you can try WEP, in case this device's default is also doing WEP (which is bad for security already)?

Comment: How can I change its security settings before I can connect to the device?

Comment: You don't change the device's setting, you change the computer's setting. That's an attempt to do. It might or might not work.

Comment: nmcli indicates the wifi is WPA1/2. Also, I couldn't find a way to change WiFi security settings on my phone nor my computer.